# An ISCSI target created by tgt can not be found by the initiator

Tags: linux, storage, iscsi

I just created an ISCSI target by tgt ,enter the command tgtadm --lld iscsi --mode target --op show
I can see:

Target 1: iqn.2009-02.com.example:for.all

```
System information:
    Driver: iscsi
    State: ready
I_T nexus information:
LUN information:
    LUN: 0
        Type: controller
        SCSI ID: IET     00010000
        SCSI SN: beaf10
        Size: 0 MB, Block size: 1
        Online: Yes
        Removable media: No
        Prevent removal: No
        Readonly: No
        SWP: No
        Thin-provisioning: No
        Backing store type: null
        Backing store path: None
        Backing store flags: 
    LUN: 1
        Type: disk
        SCSI ID: IET     00010001
        SCSI SN: beaf11
        Size: 3223 MB, Block size: 512
        Online: Yes
        Removable media: No
        Prevent removal: No
        Readonly: No
        SWP: No
        Thin-provisioning: No
        Backing store type: rdwr
        Backing store path: /dev/vda4
        Backing store flags: 
Account information:
ACL information:
    147.2.208.156
    ALL
    147.2.206.159
```

147.2.206.159 is the initiator IP ,but can not found by the initiator .I am new to ISCSI ,would someone please tell me how to correct it or what I missed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer my own question , I repeat the steps in another virtual and succeed ,so seems tgt and LIO can not run at the same machine ,that's understandable, maybe they are both trying to access or modified the same kernel iscsi module.

Hope this can help others.

does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: An iSCSI target listens on port 3260. If you start TGT and LIO (I am not sure it is possible), only one of them will be able to listen on port 3260.